# Dealing with dynamic predicates that cause compilation failures

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I am attempting to run an example GNU Prolog program used as an example during my course work. The code is pulled directly from [https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_17pl.txt](https://www.cpp.edu/%7Ejrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_17pl.txt) and was shown working at one point by my professor.

However, when I run the provided example code, I get the following compilation warning:

```
| ?- consult('C:/Users/Chase/Desktop/Prolog files/newAnimal.pro').
compiling C:/Users/Chase/Desktop/Prolog files/newAnimal.pro for byte code...
C:/Users/Chase/Desktop/Prolog files/newAnimal.pro:74:12: syntax error: . or operator expected after expression
    1 error(s)
compilation failed
```

The line that is keeping the program from compiling correctly is:

```
:- dynamic yes/1,no/1.
```

Which I read up on here: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=dynamic/1

However, despite attempting to rewrite and reformat the section, I could still not get it to compile.

Any help on why the provided code may not be running?

I am using a Windows GUI GNU Prolog console V1.4.5

Comment: I think that ```dynamic``` is not an operator in Gnu-Prolog, try to use ```:- dynamic([yes/1, no/1]).``` or ```:- dynamic(yes/1), dynamic(no/1).```.

Answer (score 2):

The ISO Prolog standard doesn't require `dynamic`(or `multifile` or `discontiguous`) to be declared as an operator. A few systems do it (e.g. SWI-Prolog like you mentioned) but not GNU Prolog. Thus, to ensure code portability, avoid using `dynamic` as an operator. Write instead:

```
:- dynamic(yes/1).
:- dynamic(no/1).
```

Or:

```
:- dynamic((yes/1, no/1)).
```

Or:

```
:- dynamic([yes/1, no/1]).
```

These are the standard conforming alternatives for declaring multiple predicates as dynamic.

Also, GNU Prolog have a fine manual (part of its installation) which you should refer to when using GNU Prolog.

Comment: Exactly what was wrong, thank you very much for the insight!

Comment: Given that `dynamic` is not declared as an operator in GNU Prolog, there can be no space between the atom `dynamic` and the directive arguments.